# How do I implement Google Sign in on Parse Server on iOS?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, google-signin, parse-server

I am using Parse Server to host my app and currently authenticate with a username and password, along with Facebook. I would also like to use Google. There seems to be no guide on how to do this, so any help would be appreciated.

I am familiar with using the Google SignIn SDK for iOS, but just not integrating it with Parse.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey Dylan, you sorted out this?

Answer (score 0):

Enable oauth on the server (will be deprecated in futher updates and changed to auth)

```
oauth: {
  google: true
},
```

On the client side create a AuthDelegate

```
class AuthDelegate : NSObject, PFUserAuthenticationDelegate {
    func restoreAuthentication(withAuthData authData: [String : String]?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Use the Google SDK to signin and get the UserID and AccessToken

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
   print(user.userID)
   print(user.authentication.accessToken)
   print(user.authentication.accessTokenExpirationDate)
}
```

Set auth data

```
let authd : [String: String] = ["id":"\(user.userID!)","expiration_date":"\(user.authentication.accessTokenExpirationDate!)","access_token":"\(gToken!)"]
```

Login in Parse via Auth

```
PFUser.logInWithAuthType(inBackground: "google", authData: authd)
```

Please note that you have think about renewal of the accesstoken yourself (client or server side)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version of implementing Google Sign in with Parse Server.

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import KVNProgress
import GoogleSignIn

class GoogleAuthWorker: NSObject {
    /// http://nsdateformatter.com
    lazy var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"
        return formatter
    }()

    var googleSignIn = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()
    var completion: (Error?) -> Void = { }
    weak var host: UIViewController?

    /// Logs in with Google. Presents Safari view controller from the host view controller.
    func logInWithGoogle(host: UIViewController?, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        self.completion = completion
        self.host = host
        PFUser.register(self, forAuthType: "google")
        googleSignIn?.delegate = self
        googleSignIn?.uiDelegate = self
        googleSignIn?.signIn()
    }
}

// MARK: - PFUserAuthenticationDelegate
extension GoogleAuthWorker: PFUserAuthenticationDelegate {
    func restoreAuthentication(withAuthData authData: [String : String]?) -> Bool {
        // Check whether expiration date is in future or not.
        guard let expirationDateString = authData?["expiration_date"],
            let expirationDate = dateFormatter.date(from: expirationDateString) else { return false }
        return expirationDate > Date()
    }
}

// MARK: - GIDSignInDelegate
extension GoogleAuthWorker: GIDSignInDelegate {
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        guard let user = user else {
            let appError = AppError.googleError(underlyingError: error)
            self.completion(.failure(error: appError))
            return
        }
        let authData: [String: String] = ["id": user.userID,
                                          "id_token": user.authentication.idToken,
                                          "expiration_date": "\(user.authentication.accessTokenExpirationDate!)",
                                          "access_token": user.authentication.accessToken]
        // Ask PFUser to log in with given auth data.
        PFUser.logInWithAuthType(inBackground: "google", authData: authData).continue({ (task) -> Any? in
            if let userObject = task.result {
                // Fill userObject (which is PFUser) by profile data, like:
                //userObject.email = user.profile.email
                //userObject.password = UUID().uuidString
                //userObject["firstName"] = user.profile.givenName
                //userObject["lastName"] = user.profile.familyName
                self.completion(nil)
            } else {
                // Failed to log in.
                self.completion(task.error)
            }
            return nil
        })
    }
}

// MARK: - GIDSignInUIDelegate
extension GoogleAuthWorker: GIDSignInUIDelegate {
    func sign(inWillDispatch signIn: GIDSignIn!, error: Error!) {
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, present viewController: UIViewController!) {
        host?.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, dismiss viewController: UIViewController!) {
        host?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```